# Ignore NaN without changing length in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, nan, spline

I am new to Python and I am trying to perform a spline interpolation. My data contains 3 columns with a number of rows having 'NaN' in one of the columns. I need to ignore/remove the NaN without reducing the length.  I have tried a number of ways, but each time the length is reduced. Any help or advice would be grateful received.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy.linalg 
import matplotlib.style
import math

data = pd.read_excel('prob_data.xlsx')
np.array(data['A'])
np.array(data['B'])
np.array(data['C'])

x = abun_data['A'][~np.isnan(abun_data['A'])]
print(len(x))
z = abun_data['B'][~np.isnan(abun_data['B'])]
print(len(z))
y = abun_data['C'][~np.isnan(abun_data['C'])]
print(len(y))
```

Comment: `data` and `abun_data` are the same ?

Comment: Yes sorry I meant to delete the abun

Answer (score 0):

You can use SimpleInputer class:

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
inputer = SimpleImputer(strategy='median')
data = pd.read_excel('prob_data.xlsx')
nice_data = pd.DataFrame(imputer.fit_transform(data))
```